# How to fill in a list of empty data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have two locations in a vector:

`ListOfLocations <- c("L1", "L2")`

I have three events happening at the above two locations in a vector:

`ListOfEvents <- c("E1", "E2", "E3")`

(In my actual data sets, I have 66 locations and 300 events.)

I have built a model to predict the probabilities of the events occurring at each of those locations with training and test sets with the actual data. Now, my task is to predict probabilities for the occurrence of the events at each of the locations for each event for the next 56 days. In order to do that, I believe that I will need empty data sets for each Location*Event combination. The code for that is as follows:

`dfNames <- apply(expand.grid(ListOfLocations, ListOfEvents), 1, function(x) paste0(x[1], x[2]))`

`dfNames`

```
[1] "Location1Event1" "Location1Event2" "Location1Event3"
[4] "Location2Event1" "Location2Event2" "Location2Event3"

newData <- setNames(replicate(length(dfNames), 
data.frame(Location = character(56),
           Event = character(56),
           Probs = double(56),
           Date = character(56),
           DayWeek = integer(56), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), simplify = FALSE), dfNames)
```

The reason I have a list of data frames is because I'd like to use the `map` function in the `purrr` package. I would like to fill in the names of the locations and events in the `Location` and `Event` variables. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could an alternative to your current approach be to create a big dataset using `expand.grid` based on your variables plus an empty variable that is 56 elements long and then use `split` to create a list based on the two factors?  That way `Location` and `Event` will already be filled in and `split` handily names each element of the list based on the two factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be using list for these kind of things instead of data.frame (simply replace `data.frame()` with `list()`. Your single "E1", "L1" values will be repeated 56 times in a data.frame.

```
Map(f = function(x) data.frame(Location = x[1],
                           Event = x[2],
                           Probs = double(56),
                           Date = character(56),
                           DayWeek = integer(56), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    x = data.frame(t(expand.grid(ListOfLocations, ListOfEvents))))
```

Map in base R works as well as the multitude of shorthand map functions in purrr.

Comment: Thank you @Vlo! `for (i in seq_along(dfNames)) {
  newData[[i]]$Location <- substr(dfNames[[i]], 1, 6)
}` 
This worked too!